# Microsoft Orleans in kubernetes StatefulSet POD crashes after several restart

Tags: consul, orleans

Microsoft Orleans v3.4.3
Consul Clustering
Running in K8S

```cs
siloBuilder
     .UseConsulClustering(opt =>
     {
         opt.Address = new Uri(AppConfig.Orleans.ConsulUrl);
         opt.AclClientToken = AppConfig.Orleans.AclClientToken;
     })
     .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
     {
         options.ClusterId = AppConfig.Orleans.ClusterID;
         options.ServiceId = AppConfig.Orleans.ServiceID;
     })
     .siloBuilder.UseKubernetesHosting();
```

I configured the labels and environment variables for my POD accordingly to the [doc](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/deployment/kubernetes.html).

```yaml
          - name: ORLEANS_SERVICE_ID #Required by Orleans 
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.labels['orleans/serviceId']
          - name: ORLEANS_CLUSTER_ID #Required by Orleans 
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.labels['orleans/clusterId']
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.labels['statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name']
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
```

It is a StatefulSet with only 1 POD for testing.
On initial startup, it works well.
However, every time when I restart the POD, a new entry is created in Consul.

[image]

And It crashes in subsequent startup.

The log says

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to get ping responses from 1 of 1 active silos. Newly joining silos validate connectivity with all active silos that have recently updated their 'I Am Alive' value before joining the cluster. Successfully contacted: []. Failed to get response from: [S10.18.123.218:11111:361110184])
 ---> Orleans.Runtime.MembershipService.OrleansClusterConnectivityCheckFailedException: Failed to get ping responses from 1 of 1 active silos. Newly joining silos validate connectivity with all active silos that have recently updated their 'I Am Alive' value before joining the cluster. Successfully contacted: []. Failed to get response from: [S10.18.123.218:11111:361110184]
   at Orleans.Runtime.MembershipService.MembershipAgent.ValidateInitialConnectivity()
   at Orleans.Runtime.MembershipService.MembershipAgent.BecomeActive()
   at Orleans.Runtime.MembershipService.MembershipAgent.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<<Orleans-ILifecycleParticipant<Orleans-Runtime-ISiloLifecycle>-Participate>g__OnBecomeActiveStart|6>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject.MonitoredObserver.OnStart(CancellationToken ct)
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken ct)
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.AsyncClosureWorkItem.Execute()
   at Orleans.Runtime.Silo.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Orleans.Hosting.SiloHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Orleans.Hosting.SiloHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at UBS.OrleansServer.EntryPoint.Start() in /app/UBS/OrleansServer/EntryPoint.cs:line 102
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have to remove all the entries in Consul then restart the POD, then everything works fine.

The `POD_NAME` is the same for StatefulSet's POD, is it correct that each POD restart creates a new entry in Consul?

What could be the cause?

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE**
After several rounds crashes and restart, finally it does not crash any more. And in log I see the following message

```
ProcessTableUpdate (called from DeclareDead) membership table: 5 silos, 1 are Active, 4 are Dead, Version=<31, 28123>. All silos: [SiloAddress=S10.18.123.244:11111:361163684 SiloName=ubs-job-dev-0 Status=Active, SiloAddress=S10.18.123.200:11111:361158057 SiloName=ubs-job-dev-0 Status=Dead, SiloAddress=S10.18.123.210:11111:361161905 SiloName=ubs-job-dev-0 Status=Dead, SiloAddress=S10.18.123.217:11111:361157424 SiloName=ubs-job-dev-0 Status=Dead, SiloAddress=S10.18.123.244:11111:361163558 SiloName=ubs-job-dev-0 Status=Dead]
```

The `SiloName` never changes and there is only one POD in StatefulSet, but it sees 5 silos, 4 of them are dead.  It seems each new POD, even if pod name does not change, is seen as a new silo.  Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

```
(Failed to get ping responses from 1 of 1 active silos. 
Newly joining silos validate connectivity with all active silos that have recently updated their 'I Am Alive' value before joining the cluster. 
Successfully contacted: []. Failed to get response from: [S10.18.123.218:11111:361110184])
```

Looks like your membershiptable (in consul) thinks that you already have active silos in it.  When your 'new' silo comes up and looks in the membershiptable it sees these `active` silos at the table's IP addresses.

To keep the cluster correct, a newly `joining` silo must be able to communicate with the existing silos.   However if the membership table is incorrect (ip address with status 3/active) then you have a problem where the new silo is trying to ping the `active` silos and not being able to reach them will fail to `join` and fast itself.

You have a couple of solutions:

- clear the consul table when deploying your solution
- change the deploymentid on every deployment.

You obviously found the first solution (clear the table)

see [silo lifecycle](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/host/silo_lifecycle.html)

Comment: even with fresh empty consul, this issue is still there,  each pod needs about 3-4 restarts to stable down